# Face recognition vs image classification

Tags: image-processing, face-recognition, face-detection, image-classification

I need to build an image classification model using tensor flow but in my datasets I have more than **10000 classes** and only **5 images** per class.

I understand that 5 is too small number of images and ideally there should be "at least" 100 images for each class, but at this point I don't understand how some "Face recognition" models can work.

For instance, all the modern smartphones provide a "face recognition" feature that can identify the phone's owner among all the faces in the world and the setup is very easy, it just needs a quick shot (3 to 5 secs) to the owner face.

So, why can this work and instead the image classification models require a high number of image to achieve an acceptable accuracy?

Are these models built using a different technology behind the scenes?

Would it be possible to build an "image classification" models using the same technology that the smartphones use for "Face recognition"?

Answer (score 1):

**Smartphone Face recognition**: What your smartphones Face recognition system does is to identify certain key features say `S`, on your face. So given a new face, it will either say "Yes this face matches with the `S`" or "No, this face does not match with the `S`". So as you can see all you need is few samples of your face to identify this good set `S`. When it sees a new face all it has to do is to get these key features from the new face and compare it with `S` and finally says "Yes" or "No". It does not have to say, it is your face or your fathers face or your mothers face etc. All it has to say is "yes it matches" or "no it does not match"

**Image classification**: However, Image classification is a totally different task, where it has to classify each image to a class. To identify if a image is a cat it has to extract certain key features which distinguish it from other animals. So if you have have 100 such different animal you need 100 such sets of distinguishable key features. This is the reason you need large samples for each class so that the Image classification system can identify such key feature set for each class.

How you identify the key features is a totally different ball game. It can be either using the classical Image processing techniques (like SIFT, SURF etc) or by using deep learning techniques (like CNNs, Autoencoder etc)